# Exclude all subdomains from google analytics view

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

What is the correct way to format a filter pattern in a Google Analytics view, so that that I can exclude all subdomains (or include only the top domain)?

Comment: This would fit better in the [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Add a filter to the View
Filter type - Predefined
Include Only - Traffic to the hostname - that are equal to
enter the top domain eg yourdomain.com in the Hostname field
*Remember to include the www if the top domain is www.